# Работая с библиотекой asposepdfcloud Python, пытался изменть текст в pdf файле, есть идеи как это решить?

Tags: python, pdf

```
import asposepdfcloud
from asposepdfcloud.apis.pdf_api import PdfApi

# Get App key and App SID from https://aspose.cloud
pdf_api_client = asposepdfcloud.api_client.ApiClient(
app_key='Пример',
app_sid='Пример')

pdf_api = PdfApi(pdf_api_client)
filename = 'CV-2.pdf'
remote_name = 'CVreplace.pdf'

#upload PDF file to storage
pdf_api.upload_file(remote_name,filename)


text_replace1 = 
asposepdfcloud.TextReplace(old_value='Facebook',new_value='aspose',regex='true')
text_replace_list = asposepdfcloud.TextReplaceListRequest(text_replaces=[text_replace1])

response = pdf_api.post_document_text_replace(remote_name, text_replace_list)

print(response)
```

Документация на github: https://github.com/aspose-pdf-cloud/aspose-pdf-cloud-python

Ожыдал что после этого кода создастся .pdf с другим текстом.
Но он не поменялся.

**Кто знает, в чём может быть проблема?**

Comment: Я предполагаю, что после изменений нужно еще вызвать метод [download_file](https://github.com/aspose-pdf-cloud/aspose-pdf-cloud-python/blob/master/docs/PdfApi.md#download_file)

Comment: insolor, попробовал, похоже что не работает.

Comment: Странно, но с pdf похоже вообще ничего не происходит.

Comment: id для скачивания берете из response или указываете имя файла, который загружали?

Comment: pdf_api.download_file('CVreplace.pdf')

Comment: @insolor Вот этот код, он сохраняет мне тот пдф что типо должен был быть с другим текстом, на пк

Comment: @insolor, попробовал заменить в другом pdf файле, заменило, наверное из-за шрифта не может заменить уже в моем. Хотя пишет что нашло слова под замену, что в моем, что в другом.

Comment: У download_file есть параметр id версии файла, но не понятно где этот id взять.